# Mongodb mlab complex findOne

Tags: json, mongodb, mlab

```
{
    "_id": "zAxNarwAE2AnvPb8P",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2018-02-28T08:48:52.840Z"
    },
    "services": {
        "password": {
            "bcrypt": "$2a$10$.Kp4OY1fXfhaZ/garVlrLOy.bLWBbaXVHXeDkfmlkmlklkSkSMOEeke"
        },
        "resume": {
            "loginTokens": [
                {
                    "when": {
                        "$date": "2018-03-02T12:53:13.447Z"
                    },
                    "hashedToken": "6B/Tpu8jQfg7XBiW5rMRsPt7+6H+HQd8AqbVQeKDu2I="
                },
 "emails": [
        {
            "address": "test@test.test",
            "verified": true
        }
    ],
    "roles": [
        "hotel"
    ],
    "pushIds": [
        "e1cf19d0-d63a-49df-bb10-cb7334c7ffb1"
    ],
    }
}
```

i want to find the document with for example hashedToken = "6B/Tpu8jQfg7XBiW5rMRsPt7+6H+HQd8AqbVQeKDu2I="

i did on mlab

```
{
    "services.resume.loginTokens": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "hashedToken": "6B/Tpu8jQfg7XBiW5rMRsPt7+6H+HQd8AqbVQeKDu2I="
        }
    }
}
```

I got a JSON Validator Error , 
close

> We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your
>   syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field
>   names and values) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, i'm sorry

```
{
    "services.resume.loginTokens": {
        "hashedToken": "iHQ2HvZUoAux4QximrlBViIy5pQuyx910aI3CL/RxDY="
    }
}
```